# "Labor-saving" as an adjective

Tags: adjectives, gerunds

> Initiatives for labor-saving

This title doesn't sound strange to me. But "labor-saving" is an adjective, so why does the title sound strange if we substitute it for other adjectives? For example,

> Initiatives for blue
>
> Initiatives for cheap

Comment: What makes you think it's an adjective in "Initiatives for labor-saving"? Substitute "fishing", "time-keeping", "ceiling-painting", etc

Comment: "labor-saving" is a gerund in this context. I'm not sure it needs to be hyphenated, since it's not being used as an adjective.

Comment: That makes sense to me. But would the verb be "labor save"? Why is that not listed in dictionaries, I wonder...

Comment: But "fishing", "time-keeping", and "ceiling-painting" are all nouns, no? Labor-saving is only listed as an adjective in the online dictionaries I have checked.

Comment: @Steven You should study what gerunds are and how they are used. The verb is "to save" with "labor" as the direct object. (The initiatives save you some labor.) When transformed into a gerund phrase, it becomes "labor-saving", in the same way as "to keep time" becomes "time-keeping".

Comment: Thank you MarcInManhattan. That's perfect! So I can use it in gerund form. The hyphen slightly bothers me though. "Decision-making" and "time-keeping" are listed as nouns whereas "labor-saving" isn't. As a gerund wouldn't it be "Initiatives for labor saving"?

Comment: Related discussion here  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361283/hyphen-in-noun-gerund-compounds

Comment: I'd say it's a verb-centred compound **noun** consisting of the noun "labor" as the first element and the deverbal noun "saving" as the second. It's functioning as object complement of the preposition "for". It can also be an adjective in, for example, "a labour-saving device".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an error.

Comment: I think it's fine, but labour-saving is clearly being used as a gerund phrase (i.e. a noun phrase) here, not as an adjective.   You say you can't find it mentioned in a dictionary as a noun, but dictionaries don't always have all meanings, and can often be outdated by the time they reach publication anyway.  Also dictionaries don't set the rules for English speakers.

Answer (score 0):

In this expression, "labor-saving" is a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) phrase, not an adjective. A gerund is a [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) form of a verb, so it can function here as the object of the preposition "for". I don't think that I've ever seen this particular gerund phrase before--I imagine that it's quite rare--but it seems feasible to me.

This gerund phrase begins with "labor", which is the direct object of "saving". This construction also appears in "time-keeping", "dog-walking", "hand-holding", etc.

The hyphen is not strictly necessary but helps to identify the gerund phrase as a single phrase. It is not common for two nominals (such as "labor" and "saving") to be adjacent, so the hyphen helps the reader to understand that they belong together. It is very common in situations such as this.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO a native speaker would say "Labour-saving initiative". It's only used as an adjective. If someone needed to start with the word "initiative" they'd use the words as single words: "Initiative to save on labour".

"Labour-saving is most commonly part of "labour-saving device", meaning a washing machine or vacuum-cleaner or other house-hold appliance. Followed by labor-saving technology or labor-saving measure. Oddly, "cost-cutting" *is* used as a noun and adjective. It's fine to say "Bob is engaged in cost-cutting" and also "Bob is implementing a cost-cutting measure". But "Bob is labour-saving" sounds odd. Because of the phrase's traditional connection to machines or processes it sounds as if Bob may be either a robot or an acronym.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. "Labour-saving" does seem to be only used as an adjective. Weirdly, the Oxford Dictionary online lists “cost-cutting” only as a noun, and then proceeds to give examples of it as an adjective.
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cost-cutting?q=cost-cutting

Comment: Two things worth noting. One is that nouns can modify other nouns, as in "the finance department", they can do that without being adjectives.